# Java 11 : problem with starting a Soap WS on karaf 4.2.7

Tags: soap, jax-ws, java-11, apache-karaf

I'm working on a java migration from java8 to java11.
Among the packages excluded on java11 is javax.xml.ws, used by the web service.
I added `jaxws-rt(2.3.3-b01)` as dependency on the pom file.
The build is OK.
Deployment was KO, because jaxws-rt was searching the ProviderImpl on jvm com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl and doesn't find it : *java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl*

After that I added two jars (`jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar` and `jaxws-rt-2.3.3-b01.jar`) on the directory `apache-karaf-4.2.7/lib/boot/` to be loaded on *karaf start*. I also added the following line:

**wrapper.java.additional.13=-Djavax.xml.ws.spi.Provider=com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl**

in **karaf-wrapper.conf** file to define the new *ProviderImpl* instead of the old one removed on Java 11.

But I still have this blocking error when starting the WS:

```
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not a subtype
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:588) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1236) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1264) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1299) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1384) ~[?:?]
        at javax.xml.ws.spi.ServiceLoaderUtil.firstByServiceLoader(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:63) ~[jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar:?]
        at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:89) ~[jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar:?]
        at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:96) ~[jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar:?]
        at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:112) ~[jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar:?]
        at fr.asipsante.psig.service.signalement.PSIGSignalement.<init>(PSIGSignalement.java:39) ~[?:?]
        at fr.gouv.sante.sivss.psig.service.PsigSignalementWebService.createPSIGSignalementWebService(PsigSignalementWebService.java:70) ~[?:?]
        at fr.gouv.sante.sivss.psig.service.PsigSignalementWebService.init(PsigSignalementWebService.java:48) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:337) ~[!/:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.invoke(BeanRecipe.java:835) ~[!/:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.runBeanProcInit(BeanRecipe.java:591) ~[!/:1.10.2]
        ... 55 more
```

I tried different solutions but still not understand what's missing... ??

NB: I can give more details if anyone wants to check information about the solution implementation.
Thanks in advance for your propositions !! Anas

Comment: Have you found a solution, because I have pretty much the same issue myself currently

Comment: Have you found a solution for the above issue, I'm also having same problem and tried the same approach but nothing is working.....at the end getting this NOT A SUB TYPE issue?

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't add those jars to the karaf lib folder. Best to add the Apache CXF feature, and then install cxf-jaxws feature. This will install CXF and the base SOAP bundles.

UPDATED (Nov 11 2020):

For your project, there are a number of things going on. I suggest starting with the Karaf SOAP example, and then adapt your code to that project. It will deploy and solve your dependency issues for SOAP-related API and Impl jars.

1. Java 8 to Java 11 changes

- XML and SOAP have been removed as standard APIs and implementations included with the JDK. Any Java 8-to-11 project now need to include these API and impl jars when deploying. However, Karaf has you covered. Install the cxf-jaxws feature and you are covered.

2. Deploying into Karaf. Did this project previously run in Karaf before?
3. SOAP implementation-- you are trying to deploy using the soap ri. Karaf has already solved all the dependency management using Apache CXF instead. I suggest you use CXF-- it has more features, and includes things like metrics, logging and security. Apache CXF is widely used across commercial and open source SOAP products for enterprise use cases.
4. Karaf has an out-of-the-box SOAP example that works:

   - [Karaf SOAP Example](https://github.com/apache/karaf/tree/master/examples/karaf-soap-example)
5. Your log statement indicates using the Eclipse OSGi runtime, instead of Karaf's default Felix. Is there a reason to switch?

Comment: It doesn't help....     Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.xml.ws; version="[2.3.0,3.0.0)"

 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444) ~[?:?]
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:383) ~[?:?]

Comment: I updated my answer.. I have no idea why someone would down vote it. Fun at SO